# making an integer vector from index of another vector in R

Tags: r, indexing, subset

I have just started to learn R, and trying to do the following task.

I have a vector of 10 random values few are NAs and few are numeric values in it, like

```
 a <- rnorm(100)
 b <- rep(NA, 100)
 c <- sample(c(a, b), 10)
```

now I want to make another vector "d" which has indices of all the NA values in "c" for example

```
 d <- c(2, 7, 9)
```

I tried

```
 d <- which(c %in% is.na(c))
```

but its not giving me desired result

also what is wrong with this code i tried for the above purpose

```
navects <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:length(x)) {
       if(is.na(x[i])) c(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , it solved my purpose, and if possible can you please look at that small piece of code, and point out errors in it.

Comment: You need to do something like this `navects <- function(x) {
   v1 <- c();
   for(i in 1:length(x)) {
        if(is.na(x[i])) v1[i] <- c(i)
   };
 v1[!is.na(v1)];
 }`, but why going this loop route if can solve it with a one line code.

Comment: Thank you very much akrun :-), yes you are right there is no need to go for loop when single line function is there, But when i was stuck at it I tried whatever crossed my mind, and was curious.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `which`

```
 which(is.na(c))
```

NOTE: `c` is also a function, so it is better not to name objects with `c`.